# as fluent as or as fluently as?

Tags: grammar

Which is grammatically correct? as fluent as or as fluently as?

> Lisa can't speak English as (fluency - fluently - fluent) as her sister.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fluently** is the correct choice and here's why. First of all, you need to understand what part of speech the word **fluently** is. It's an adverb. Adverbs in their function are very similar to adjectives whose job it is to modify nouns. The job of an adverb, on the other hand, is to modify verbs. **fluently** in your example is modifying the verb **speak**. It tells you how Lisa CAN'T speak English—she can't speak it as fluently as her sister:

> Lisa can't speak English as **fluently** as her sister.

The other two words in your list are **fluency** and **fluent**. The first one is a noun and the other one is an adjective. Nouns identify people, things or ideas and adjectives, as was mentioned above, modify (or give attributes) to nouns. So, if you want to use **fluent** or **fluency** instead of **fluently** in your sentence, the grammar of the sentence needs to be fixed a little bit to reflect the necessary changes:

> Lisa is not as **fluent** in English as her sister.
>
> Lisa's **fluency** of English is not as good as that of her sister's.

Answer (score 2):

I think *fluently* should be used in this sentence, because the adverb *fluently* modifies the verb *speak*.

> Lisa can't speak English as fluently as her sister.